# Use a sub domain to act as a folder

Tags: mod-rewrite, subdomain

I have this code:

```
# Use WordPress subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain.co.uk
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp/(.*)$
RewriteRule .* http://wp.domain.co.uk/%1 [L]
```

This works, exactly how I want it to, so when you go to domain.co.uk/wp/index.php it shows the page wp.domain.co.uk/index.php.

However, rather than it redirecting you in the browser to the physical address wp.domain.co.uk/index.php I would like it to display domain.co.uk/wp/index.php.

Is that possible?

Thanks,

Ian

Answer (score 1):

If the `domain.co.uk` and `wp.domain.co.uk` domains don't share a common document root (or if the latter isn't in a subdirectory of the former), you'll need to rely on mod_proxy. This won't work unless you have mod_proxy enabled. You'll just need to add a `P` flag to your `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteRule .* http://wp.domain.co.uk/%1 [L,P]
```

Otherwise, if they share the same document root, just remove the `http://wp.domain.co.uk` and point it to the appropriate place within your document root.

Comment: They are on different servers, I will have a look into mod_proxy

Comment: I now get a proxy error: http://sightcare.co.uk/wp/index.php. I have turned mod_proxy on in httpd.conf and set Allow from wp.sightcare.co.uk, any ideas?

Comment: @IanJamieson you shouldn't need to setup any Allows. What error are you getting?

Comment: if you go to that link, I get a 502 Proxy error, Reason: DNS lookup failure for: wp.sightcare.co.uk

Comment: @IanJamieson "**DNS lookup failure for: wp.sightcare.co.uk**" seems that's what you need to resolve. The `sightcare.co.uk` apparently isn't able to resolve the `wp.sightcare.co.uk` hostname.

Comment: @IanJamieson it could be any number of things, including not properly configured services, not properly configured OS, not properly configured DNS records for the `sightcare.co.uk` domain, etc. If you're using some sort of OS that allows for hosts files, create one resolving `wp.sightcare.co.uk` to whatever IP it's residing at. You may want to ask how to fix your DNS over at superuser.com or serverfault.com, as this is system administration.